# Simple content slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple content slider to show customer reviews in three slides. This is the code I have so far [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dak8J/), however somehow it shows me like 3+ slides (instead of showing the three divs, it shows way more "empty" ones) So after the third slide it should start at the 1st slide again.

Another problem that I have is that it seem to work on JSfiddle, but when I copy and paste it into my html it won't work.

The two lines that I've added in my html are

```
<script src="Webdesign/NagelsalonHintham/js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, the reason that you get more slides than you'd like is because you need to be more specific in your JS.

Your next and prev button event handlers use a jQuery animation to move the 'slidie' div - this is fine. However you need to add some extra logic in order to stop the div being animated further and further away if there are no more slides to show in that particular direction. I have altered your JS to implement what I believe you'd like:

```
var sliderWidth = 300;
var slider = $('#slidie');
var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);

var currentSlide = 1;

$('a.prev').click(function () {
    if (currentSlide > 1) {
        $('#slidie').animate({
            left: '+=' + sliderWidth
        }, 500);
        currentSlide -= 1;
    }
});

$('a.next').click(function () {
    if (currentSlide < sliderCount) {
        $('#slidie').animate({
            left: '-=' + sliderWidth
        }, 500);
        currentSlide += 1;
    }
});
```

All I have added is an extra variable called `currentSlide` which is initialised to 1. This is necessary for you to keep track of which slide is currently being shown to the user.

Then, in both event handlers you check to see if `currentSlide` is such that the animation is allowed to take place. You only want the prev button to work if the current slide is `> 1`, i.e. you are not on the first slide. Similarly, you only want the next button to work if the current slide is `< sliderCount`, i.e. you are not on the final slide.

You must also make sure to alter `currentSlide` after you perform an animation to keep it in sync with what the user is currently seeing. This is done with the `currentSlide -= 1` and `currentSlide += 1` lines of code.

To answer your second question, I imagine the problem you have is that jQuery has not finished loading before your code is executed. I would firstly re-order your script tags in the HTML so that jQuery is loaded first:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Webdesign/NagelsalonHintham/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Additionally, for safety reasons I would wrap your code in a jQuery DOM ready event. This basically means that the code you write is only executed once the DOM (the framework that allows JS to access the HTML page) has finished being constructed by your browser. Therefore if you refer to any tags (which you do) you know the tags actually exist before the JS runs. This is illustrated below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your code from above goes here

});
```

The reason it works in JSFiddle is because they do the jQuery including for you, including putting your code in the right place (by default). You can change that in the left hand side of the JSFiddle window.

For reference, the working JSFiddle for this solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/EULJd/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the javascript code in between the document ready tag you showed, however it is still not working when previewing the homepage in html. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have found it! The solution was indeed to put the code between document ready tags and i forgot to put the http:// in front of the jquery link.

Comment: Good to hear it works, and yes - not including 'http://' would give the browser an incorrect URL for the jQuery script. You can also refer to an external script using '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', i.e. omitting the 'http:'. This is shorthand that tells the browser "use the current protocol to access this URL", so if your site is using plain HTTP, it uses 'http://' but if your site uses HTTPS, it uses 'https://' which is useful in the latter case - it's more secure. Browsers actually complain if you include non-HTTPS resources when using HTTPS to serve your page.

Comment: Ted, I want to add this same javascript a second time on my page with other ids and classes. Is there a special way to do it, cause I have changed everything according to the new divs, but it does not seem to work when opening the "preview"..